# Applying C2RCC atmospheric correction to Sentinel-2 L1C images in SNAP

Tags: sentinel-2, atmospheric-correction, jpeg-2000, sentinel-snap

Sentinel-2 Level-1C images are available [in this AWS bucket](https://registry.opendata.aws/sentinel-2/). I am trying to get a Sentinel-2 L1C image of an area with an atmospheric correction done by the [C2RCC Processor](https://seadas.gsfc.nasa.gov/help-8.0.0/c2rcc/C2RCCTool.html). I try to do this using [SNAP Desktop](https://eo4society.esa.int/resources/snap/).

**My question: how do I get Sentinel-2 L1C C2RCC processed images - ie how do I fix the attempt below?**

---

I downloaded one of them, using the command:

```
aws s3 cp s3://sentinel-s2-l1c/tiles/39/R/WJ/2020/8/22/0/B04.jp2 L1C/B04.jp2 --request-payer requester
```

Then, opened [SNAP Desktop](https://eo4society.esa.int/resources/snap/), clicked the open folder "Open Product" symbol on the top left, gave the path of my `B04.jp2` image. After loading, I can view the image:

[image]

If I then select `Optical` from the top menu bar, then `Thematic Water Processing` -> `C2RCC Processors` -> `S2-MSI`, I get:

[image]

After clicking `Run`, I get:

[image]

Relying on this message, I click `Optical` -> `Geometric` -> `S2 Resampling Processor`. I get:

[image]

click `Run`, result:

[image]

---

**EDIT**

Following comments, I realize I need a `.safe`  file. To get one, I do:

```
aws s3 ls s3://sentinel-s2-l1c/products/2020/10/30/S2B_MSIL1C_20201030T235749_N0209_R030_T57MVN_20201031T010920/ --request-payer requester
```

(The choice of date is not important.) This returns:

```
                       PRE datastrip/
```

2020-10-31 03:44:30      18953 inspire.xml
2020-10-31 03:44:30      73519 manifest.safe
2020-10-31 03:44:30      44305 metadata.xml
2020-10-31 03:44:31       1039 productInfo.json

`manifest.safe` has the extension we want. Download:

```
aws s3 cp s3://sentinel-s2-l1c/products/2020/10/30/S2B_MSIL1C_20201030T235749_N0209_R030_T57MVN_20201031T010920/manifest.safe manifest.safe --request-payer requester
```

When I try to open this file using SNAP, I get:

[image]

which is not entirely unexpected given that [this site](https://sentinels.copernicus.eu/web/sentinel/user-guides/sentinel-2-msi/data-formats) says:

> manifest.safe file [...] holds the general product information in XML

So I don't know how to open a `.safe` file and have a viewable image in SNAP as a result.

Comment: Have you tried pointing it at a .SAFE folder, rather than a specific band?

Comment: No. Looking up what `.SAFE` folder means...

Comment: It is the full & raw S2 file structure. All of the bands and the metadata in the correct organization.

Comment: Oh ok. Thank you. So If I copy all the files to a directory from `s3://sentinel-s2-l1c/tiles/39/R/WJ/2020/8/22/0/`, that will be a SAFE folder containing measurements from 2020.08.22, about the area specified by the `39/R/WJ` part of the filename - is this understanding of `.SAFE` files correct?

Comment: I tried what I said above, I was wrong.

Comment: You need to download the data in the proper format. I don't usually download data the way that you do, so I don't know exactly how to force aws to give it to you in the right way.

Comment: https://sentinels.copernicus.eu/web/sentinel/user-guides/sentinel-2-msi/data-formats

Comment: Thank you @MikkelLydholmRasmussen. I found `.safe` files on AWS, but the one I have currently isn't cutting it (added this to post).

Answer (score 1):

The C2RCC requires all the bands resampled by S2Resample before processing. In the S2Resample I/O window, select MTD_MSIL1C.xml file from the .SAFE folder of Sentinel-2 product you are processing. It will import all the bands and the required metadata.